# Django save metadata -[Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, django

I got a question. I got an issue with the path:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory:

I've tried with:

```
url = self.image.url
image_meta = image.open(url)
```

then in adding the the first part of URL "https://...." + self.image.url
I still got the same issue do you have any idea

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    catego = models.ForeignKey(Catego,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="catego_pictures")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nutriscore/')
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    date = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    software = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    metadata = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    pictureoption = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Pictureoption.choices,default=Pictureoption.HOME,)
    publishing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        url = self.image.url
        full_path = os.listdir(url)
        image_meta = image.open(full_path)
        
        exif = {}
        for tag, value in image_meta.get_exif().items():
            if tag in TAGS:
                exif[TAGS[tag]] = value
                
        if 'DateTime' in exif:
            self.date = DateTime
        if 'Software' in exif:
            self.software = Software
        if 'Artist' in exif:
            self.artist = Artist
        ...

    
        self.metadata = exif
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.catego.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `.path` property of your image object, instead of the `.url`, since it seems that you're trying to reach the file with it's local path, instead of fetching it as a web resource.

Comment: I got the same issue with .path. My Django is not local but online.

Comment: Look at your code. Your doing `url = self.image.url ; full_path = os.listdir(url)`, which means "give me the URL of this image, and then try to list the content of the URL. That doesn't make absolutely no sense at all. Get the image's path with `.path`, then get the directory of that path wth `os.path.basename`.